# Is it possible to generate changelog diffs?

Tags: liquibase

I've got my baseline snapshot created using the `generateChangeLog` command. I've made some changes and I'm trying to figure out how to generate a changeset file by doing some sort of diff but it seems like that isn't a concept in Liquibase and those need to be created manually. XML also appears to be the preferred format but are we expected to hand-write xml files? Seems like this could be automated easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the `diff-changelog` command.  Here's the relevant copy from the documentation.

> Running the `diff-changelog` command requires two URLs:
>
> - **`referenceURL`** – the source for the comparison. The `referenceURL` attribute represents your source (reference) database which is the starting point and the basis for the database you want to compare.
> - **`url`** – the target of the comparison. The `URL` attribute stands for your target database which you want to compare to the source (reference) database. You typically perform actions and run the commands against this database.
>
> To create a diff changelog:
>
> The first option is to run the `diff-changelog` command and pass the attributes needed for your source (reference) database and target database.

As an example, you can run the following:

```
liquibase
--changelog-file=dbchangelog.xml
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP OR HOSTNAME>:<PORT>:<SERVICE NAME OR SID>"
--username=<USERNAME>
--password=<PASSWORD>
--referenceUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP OR HOSTNAME>:<PORT>:<SERVICE NAME OR SID>"
--referenceUsername=<USERNAME>
--referencePassword=<PASSWORD>              
diff-changelog
```

Reference:

1. [Running the diff-changelog command](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/diff/diff-changelog.html)